# jQuery hide other <div>, not this <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm generating several divs with id="RG":

```
<div id="rg"></div>
<div id="rg"></div>
<div id="rg"></div>
```

If I was to click on the first div, how could I hide every div but the div clicked.

```
<div id="rg"></div> <-- Clicked (Keep)
<div id="rg"></div> <-- Hide
<div id="rg"></div> <-- Hide
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID, use class instead

Comment: Not strictly, but you *can't* realistically have multiple element's sharing an ID. An ID is unique!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you can/should only use an ID once i.e. each ID attribute's value must be unique.

Second, it would look like this

```
$('div').click(function() {
   $(this).siblings().hide();
}):
```

Comment: +1 on the All html elements need to have unique id's. If you want them all to have the same selector use class which is allowed to be non-unique

Answer (score 4):

You should *not* use the same ID multiple times, use classes instead.

```
<div class="rg"></div>
```

Then simply do:

```
$(".rg").click(function(){
    $(".rg").not(this).hide();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nTs8H/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're not supposed to have multiple elements with same id. Use `<div class="rg"></div>` instead.

If you change them to classes, you could use the following code:

```
$(".rg").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings(".rg").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#rg').click(function(e){
    $(this).siblings().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use IDs twice so switch them to classes and use this:

```
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('.rg').click(function() {
                    $('.rg').hide();
                    $(this).show();
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as mentioned in a comment, you should use class instead of id since id should be unique. 
I can't provide a jQuery solution, but I can give you a general thing.

So, when you click on the div, this div should be passed as a parameter to the listener. (I think) 
To hide all others you have to find all divs with class=rg

This should be something like jQuery(".rg").hide()

Then, after you hide ALL divs, you should show the div, on which the user has clicked.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="rg1" class="toggle"></div>
<div id="rg2" class="toggle"></div>
<div id="rg3" class="toggle"></div>
```

then add onclick event for each div (#rg1 - in example)

```
$('.toggle').css('display','none');$('#rg1').css('display','block');
```

this solution for situations when other divs (or other tags) not siblings too