# Hiding the Div Element

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to hide the other div which is the number identifier is equal to 1

I have 3 div

Each of this div has the same class "roomselection"

But they are different in number for identifier

For Example

```
<div class="roomselection1">
    <button class="unselect">Unselect</button>
</div>
<div class="roomselection2"></div>
<div class="roomselection3"></div>
```

Here i want only to hide the roomselection2 and roomselection3

I want in my jquery is that

It will check all the div that has class "roomselection"

It will detect the roomselection1 div

if you notice the button unselect in roomselection1
- it because once it was click the other div be will hide but the roomselection1 the one that will appear.

Comment: So you're asking how to hide `roomselection2` and`roomselection3` when you click on `unselect` in `roomselection1`?

Comment: You only have one class on your elements. Add a class `roomselection` to all your div's (`<div class="roomselection roomselection1">`), then you can select all those elements with `$('.roomselection')`.

Comment: Thank you for that bright idea . Im really sorry because i've been focusing only to roomselection + n @ssc-hrep3. Just a few changes then i resolved my problem. using this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517445/jquery-hide-other-div-not-this-div

Comment: 'Each of this div has the same class "roomselection"' - no, no they don't. You have 3 different classes with a common prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-

```
<div class="roomselection" id="div1">hi
    <button class="unselect">Unselect</button>
</div>
<div class="roomselection" id="div2">hello</div>
<div class="roomselection" id="div3">welcome</div>
```

JQuery-

```
$(function() {
        $('.unselect').click(function(){
        var classes = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
        $('.roomselection').hide();
        $('#' + classes).show();

        });
    });
```

Hope it helps!